# iOS UITableViewCell Images from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am loading images in my `UITableViewCell` from some web url and those images are in size around 80-100 kb per image. Everything works fine when i download images asynchronously `but when i scroll the tableview, images start again downloading. Can i get rid of this` as i have only limited no of rows. 
I want if images from url download once should not be download again as it does  makes view not comfortable for users when images starts downloading again.

I am using below code to load images in `CellforRowAtIndexPath`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    if ( data == nil )
        return;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.eventImage.image=  [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    });
});
```

Comment: Use SDWebImage it cache image and load fast after first download.https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SDWebImage` which will cache image on your device and if same image came from server then it load from your local device.

1. Add SDWebImage to your project.
2. import `<SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` header

   then add below code at `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

   ```
   [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your image URL"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Better make use of SDWebImageCache for this because this a advantageous third party library to store the image in cache. After downloading once the images will be taken automatically from the cache.

[SDWebImageCache](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

When you Download image put it to the document directory and before you download image check if document directory contains image then load it from there otherwise download from URL

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can make it yourself. You can use NSCache in order to save your images. NSCache it is like NSMutableDictionary (save your image by key). And then you can check it. For key you can use path to your image.
But I also recommend you to use *[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)*.